# Jqgrid huge data load problems

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid, large-data

I am doing some investigation on jqgrid, everything works fine, until I load the huge data which contains about 1M lines in database, jqgrid don't display now, when I downsize the lines of the database to 100K, the data will display, but I still needs to refresh the page several times, I downsize to 10K, it works fine, I am not sure the jqgrid has a size limited? and more, I can save the data to local file which returns by the url, and upload it to the server, and the change the url to the file and jqgrid can display it....

Can anybody help me out? Code is here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
            $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
            $(function() {
                $("#griddisplay").jqGrid({
                    url:'<spring:url value="/charts/search/sub"/>',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype:'POST',
                    colNames:['id','time_stamp', 'user_name','name','parameter'],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id',width:160},
                        {name:'time_stamp',index:'time_stamp',width:160},
                        {name:'user_name',index:'user_name',width:160},
                        {name:'name',index:'name',width:160},
                        {name:'parameter',index:'parameter', width:100}
                    ],          
                    rowNum:100,
                    rowList:[100,50,25],
                    height: 500,
                    autowidth: true,
                    rownumbers: true,
                    pager: '#pager',
                    sortname: 'time_stamp',
                    gridview: true,
                    //viewrecords: true,
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    //emptyrecords: "<fmt:message key='msg.report.table.noreport' />",
                    loadonce: false,
                    //multiselect: false,
                    //loadComplete: function() {
                    //},
                    //caption: "Video Grid",
                    jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false,
                        id: "id",
                        root: "rows",
                        page: "page",
                        total: "total",
                        records: "records"
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

the json data is below:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "total": 2,
    "records": 2,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 9901,
            "time_stamp": "2011-04-12",
            "user_name": "abcd",
            "name": "somehere",
            "parameter": "harry"
        },
        {
            "id": 9902,
            "time_stamp": "2011-04-12",
            "user_name": "abcd",
            "name": "somehere",
            "parameter": "harry"
        }
    ]
}
```

get all the counts from oracle database

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public long getLogbaksRecords() {
    String sql="select count(*) from test";
    long lbs=jdbcTemplate.queryForLong(sql);
    System.out.println("lbs="+lbs);
    return lbs;
}
```

get the data

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<LogbakBean> getLogbaks(String sidx, String sord, String rows,int p) {
    String sql="SELECT * FROM(SELECT A.*, ROWNUM RN FROM (SELECT time_stamp,parameter,user_name,name FROM test order by "+sidx+" "+sord+") A WHERE ROWNUM <= "+p*Integer.valueOf(rows)+")WHERE RN > "+(p-1)*Integer.valueOf(rows);
    System.out.println("query start"+sql);
    List<LogbakBean> lbs=jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<LogbakBean>(){

        public LogbakBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                throws SQLException {
            //LOG.info("getLogbaks===mapRow");
            LogbakBean lb=new LogbakBean();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String time=sdf.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(rs.getString("time_stamp"))));
            lb.setTime_stamp(time);
            lb.setParameter(rs.getString("parameter"));
            lb.setUser_name(rs.getString("user_name"));
            lb.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            lb.setId(Long.valueOf(rs.getString("RN")));
            //System.out.println("curt rows="+rs.getString(5));
            //LOG.info("getLogbaks===mapRow===finish");
            return lb;
        }

    });
    System.out.println("query end");
    return lbs;
}
```

the web controller which returns data to jqgrid

```
@RequestMapping(value="/charts/search/sub",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void searchResult(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("page")String page,
        @RequestParam("rows")String rows,
        @RequestParam("sidx")String sidx,
        @RequestParam("sord")String sord) throws IOException{

    int p= Integer.parseInt(page);
    int t=Integer.parseInt(rows);
    System.out.println("p="+p+"t="+t);
    long logs=services.getLogbaksRecords();
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("page", p);
    obj.put("total",logs%t==0?logs/t:logs/t+1);
    obj.put("records",logs);
    System.out.println("total records="+logs);
    JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();
    List<LogbakBean> lgb=services.getLogbaks(sidx,sord,rows,p);
    for(int i=0;i<lgb.size();i++){
        JSONObject o=new JSONObject();
        LogbakBean l=lgb.get(i);
        o.put("id", l.getId());
        o.put("time_stamp", l.getTime_stamp());
        o.put("user_name",l.getUser_name());
        o.put("name",l.getName());
        o.put("parameter",l.getParameter());
        arr.add(o);
        LOG.info(l.getTime_stamp()+","+l.getUser_name()+","+l.getName()+","+l.getParameter());
    }
    obj.put("rows", arr);
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
    //OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createCompactFormat();
    //JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter();
    //writer.
    //return obj;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't transfer such amount of data through the wire.
jqGrid uses a paging system which allows you to return chunks of data to the grid.

Basically what I would do is implement some sort of pagination of your data server-side.

Comment: Yes, i do make paging on the server side, i fetch 100 row from server in 1M row data one time, seems the data returned a little slow due to the data is large, even through i downsize the data to only one row, the jqgrid also don't display. any comments?

Comment: @Victor: I reckon that the problem is server-side. Your server is too busy fetching 1M rows and jqGrid is waiting.

Comment: @Victor: I think that LeftyX are right. I also suppose that you should verify the code which you used for the paging of data. Which SELECT statement will be executed? How many time the server code took? Which database you has (MS SQL SERVER, MySQL, ...)? jqGrid just use the values from `page`, `total` and `records` from the JSON server response. It must be unimportant whether you has 200 or 2000000 rows in the server database. Nevertherless you can reduce the size of data twice if you whould use `jsonReader:{cell:"",id:"0"}` and the corresponding JSON data. Additionally I would use `rowNum:25`

Comment: Thanks LeftX and Oleg, i am very appreciated, the json server return data in about 3 or 4 seconds, some times it costs even more time, i use oracle database, first i use sql count(*) to get the total records and use the select to get the data by total records, i have added the code of getting data form server. Thanks.

Comment: And more if the server returns data is slow, and the jqgrid will not display the data? and for this condition, what should i do? thanks so much

Comment: Finally, the problems resolved, just because i use multiselect in the grid page, the multiselect is conflict with the jqgrid, please see the code i update above. tanks Oleg and leftyX

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problems resolved, just because i use multiselect in the grid page, the multiselect is conflict with the jqgrid, please see the code i update above. tanks Oleg and leftyX

the conflict code is below

```
$(function(){
    $.localise('ui-multiselect', {/*language: 'zh',*/ path: '<spring:url value="/resources/scripts/multiselect/" />'});
    $(".multiselect").multiselect();
});
```

when i removed the code, the problems resolved. thanks everyone.